# Adding elements to Listview in jqueryMobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have a listview. I need to add and remove from the list. On adding to the list, the jquery mobile styling does not get added to the new content.

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="contributionList">
   <li id="l1"><a>5.00</a><a data-icon="delete" data-role="button" id="1"></a></li>
   <li><a>10.00</a><a data-icon="delete" data-role="button"></a></li>
   <li><a>15.00</a><a data-icon="delete" data-role="button"></a></li>
   <li><a>20.00</a><a data-icon="delete" data-role="button"></a></li>
   <li><a>25.00</a><a data-icon="delete" data-role="button"></a></li>
   <li><a>50.00</a><a data-icon="delete" data-role="button"></a></li>
   <li><a>100.00</a><a data-icon="delete" data-role="button"></a></li> 
</ul>
```

I have a fieldset to add amounts to the list.

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
   <div class="ui-block-a">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add new Amount" id="contributionAmount" />
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b">
     <input type="button" value="Add" id="addContribution"/>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

I am using the append function to end other amounts that are added to the list. The amount gets added, but the styling (i.e. jquery mobile) classes do not get applied to the new added  amount.
Can someone tell me on how to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it working:

- http://jsfiddle.net/NXrRp/10/

JS

```
$('.deleteMe').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('#contributionList').listview('refresh');
});

$('#addContribution').click(function() {
    var newAmount = $('#contributionAmount').val();

    if(newAmount != '') {
        $('#contributionList').append('<li><a>' + newAmount + '</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>').listview('refresh');
        $('#contributionAmount').val('');
    } else {
        alert('Nothing to add');   
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="contributionList" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="d">
           <li id="l1"><a>5.00</a><a id="1" class="deleteMe"></a></li>
           <li><a>10.00</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>
           <li><a>15.00</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>
           <li><a>20.00</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>
           <li><a>25.00</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>
           <li><a>50.00</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>
           <li><a>100.00</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li> 
        </ul>
        <br />
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
           <div class="ui-block-a">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Add new Amount" id="contributionAmount" />
           </div>
           <div class="ui-block-b">
             <input type="button" value="Add" id="addContribution"/>
           </div>
        </fieldset>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves the issue I was trying to figure out for almost 3hrs.

Comment: Why does the $(document).ready function get called twice. While adding the amount, they get added twice.

Comment: @Hozefa you should not be using $(document).ready with jQM, Search for related questions

Answer (score 4):

You have to refresh the `listview` for jQuery Mobile to add the correct classes to the correct elements in your `listview`:

```
$('#addContribution').on('click', function () {
    var amount_val = $('#contributionAmount').val();
    if (amount_val != '') {
        $('#the-listview').append('<li>' + amount_val + '</li>').listview('refresh');
    }
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PQ39n/1/

Docs for jQuery Mobile `listview`s: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

**EDIT**

Phill Pafford brings-up a good point that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and the jQuery Mobile team suggest using jQuery 1.6.4 with jQuery Mobile 1.0. In this case `.on()` is the same as using `.bind()` so they can be interchanged without issue.

Comment: @Jasper FYI the .on() is not available in jQuery 1.6.4 which is the supported version of jQm 1.0 Otherwise +1

Comment: @PhillPafford Yeah I used 1.6.4 for a while but then got interested in what would break if I moved to 1.7 and the only thing I've noticed is slightly faster event handling (I have yet to see anything break).

Comment: @Jasper: Why does the $(document).ready function get called twice. While adding the amount, they get added twice.

Comment: @Hozefa I don't understand your question. `document.ready` firing twice wouldn't have anything to do with the `click` event code.

Comment: @Jasper I am using the .click() event. So, the amount gets added twice, on a single click. So, what I meant is that why is the event getting fired twice.

Comment: @Jasper: For the #addContribution id, I am having only one click event. So, for this particular id, I am using the event only once.

Comment: @Hozefa Events like `click` bubble up the DOM all the way to the `document` node. So if you are binding this event handler to an element that is a parent (at some level) of the `#addContribution` button then it will fire after the event handler for `#addContribution` fires and two list-items will be appended instead of one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5901/discussion-between-hozefa-and-jasper)